# how to find out how many sets have elements only from another set

Tags: matlab, set, element

I am looking for an efficient way to determine how many sets consist of another set elements in Matlab.

Example:
U ={[1 2],[2 3],[3 4],[4 5],[5 6],[6 7],[1 7],[1 9],[3 9],[6 8],[8 9],[4 9],[5 8]};
V=[1 2 3 4 9];

[1 2],[2 3],[3 4],[1 9],[3 9],[4 9] so answer: 6 sets consist of V set elements

how to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 U2=U(cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(x,V)),U));
```

The result is:

```
 U2{:}

ans =
     1     2
ans =
     2     3
ans =
     3     4
ans =
     1     9
ans =
     3     9
ans =
     4     9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical indexing to solve this problem:

```
U={[1 2],[2 3],[3 4],[4 5],[5 6],[6 7],[1 7],[1 9],[3 9],[6 8],[8 9],[4 9],[5 8]};
V=[1 2 3 4 9];
Um=cell2mat(U');
A=Um(ismember(Um(:,1),V)&ismember(Um(:,2),V),:);
```